# cron.php problem in Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, crontab

When i run cron.php like  http://www.YOURDOMAIN.com/PATH_TO_MAGENTO/cron.php on my local server wamp i get a white page which means is runs properly.

But when i run on my remote server i get magento page saying There was no `404 CMS page configured or found`.

This means `cron.php` isn't running properly?

I'm running `cron.php` via cronjob in my cpanel like this `/opt/alt/php56/usr/bin/php /home/path/to/magento/cron.php >> /home/path/to/magento/var/log/cron.log.`

**Update:**

Including `$isShellDisabled = true;` make it work with cronjob `/opt/alt/php56/usr/bin/php /home/path/to/magento/cron.php >> /home/path/to/magento/var/log/cron.log`.
Then i changed cronjob to `/bin/sh /home/path/to/magento/cron.sh > /home/path/to/magento/var/log/cron_sh.log` and it also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Cron.php` file not excute from browser because it is restricted from `.htaccess` file. You can comment the below two lines in .htaccess file at the bottom, then it will work.

```
<Files cron.php>
    #Order allow,deny
    #Deny from all
</Files>
```

You can also add the below line in `cron.php` file

```
$isShellDisabled = true;
```

after the below code:

```
$isShellDisabled = is_array($disabledFuncs) ? in_array('shell_exec', $disabledFuncs) : true;
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
```

Comment: Seems like its working after making the change. I also removed another cronjob it was there `php -f /home/path/to/magento/cron.php`. I guess the other cronjob wouldn't be the problem. Thanks for saving my day.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i dont know why its showing 404 page. Rather it should show

> You don't have permission to access /cron.php on this server.
>   Apache/2.4.23 (Win64) PHP/5.6.25 Server at domain.magento.com Port 80

Because if you open `.htaccess` file in magento root you will find this

```
###########################################
## Deny access to cron.php
    <Files cron.php>
       Order allow,deny
       Deny from all
    </Files>
```

Its good because no one should access `cron.php` file through browser.

**Now the most important part is... you should never run `cron.php` file through browser.** Rather run `cron.sh`. This file also calls `cron.php` internally. And this wont start running again if its already running which `cron.php` does.

Comment: Is cron.sh called the same way?
`/opt/alt/php56/usr/bin/php /home/path/to/magento/cron.sh >> /home/path/to/magento/var/log/cron.log`

Comment: No. Its not a php file. Its a .sh file. So the command is `sh cron.sh`

Comment: I think it should be `/bin/sh`. I'm executing via Cpanel cronjob.

Comment: May be yes. Depends on your server.

Comment: I'm using `/bin/sh /home/path/to/magento/cron.sh > /home/path/to/magento/var/log/cron_sh.log` and it's running. Thank you very much.